# pull down to refresh tableview

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.ios

I created a tableview with values that come form an api. now I want to refresh the values by pulling down on the tableview.

the problem is that it doesn't execute, I tried it with placing breakpoints on the used code.

here is the code I put in my viewdidload from the tableview:

```
        refreshControl = new MvxUIRefreshControl();
        refreshControl.ValueChanged += refreshTable;
        TableView.AddSubview(refreshControl);
```

refreshtable void:

```
   private void refreshTable(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            refreshControl.EndRefreshing();
            TableView.ReloadData();
         }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: oh sorry will add in post!

Comment: @ChaitanyaKumar i edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `MvxUIRefreshControl` you should create a command to handle this event.

**In your ViewModel the command may be like this:**

```
private MvxCommand refreshCommand;
public ICommand RefreshCommand
{
    get
    {
        return refreshCommand ?? (refreshCommand = new MvxCommand(ExecuteRefreshCommand));
    }
}

// Define this property to let the refresh control stop
private bool isBusy;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get { return isBusy; }
    set
    {
        isBusy = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsBusy);
    }
}

async private void ExecuteRefreshCommand()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    // Do your task
    // await Task.Delay(2000);
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

**Then in your View, the binding should be like this:**

```
var control = new MvxUIRefreshControl();
TableView.AddSubview(control);

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<YourView, YourViewModel>();

set.Bind(control).For(s => s.IsRefreshing).To(vm => vm.IsBusy);
set.Bind(control).For(s => s.RefreshCommand).To(vm => vm.RefreshCommand);

set.Apply();
```

Comment: that works! only one edit, you referenced the wrong void in your mvxcommand!

Comment: in your refreshcommand you want to acces "ExecuteRefreshCommand" but that should be "ExecuteReloadCommand"